# How to trigger INSERT with no values into PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a members table with four columns.

```
table members.tbl_member as U {
  member_id int [pk, increment]
  date_created timestamp [not null, default: `CURRENT_DATE`]
  date_modified timestamp [not null, default: `CURRENT_DATE`]
  date_security timestamp [not null, default: `CURRENT_DATE`]
}
```

(create script from DbDiagram)

Every column is either a auto increment primary key, or has a default value.

I want to be able to trigger an insertion on this row, and return the inserted row, but to do this I don't need or want to insert any values for any timestamp as the that is handled by the defaults.

```
INSERT INTO members.tbl_member
       VALUES (nothing!)
       RETURNING 
            member_id AS MemberID,
            date_created AS DateCreated, 
            date_modified AS DateModified,
            date_security AS DateSecurity
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Unrelated, but might be interesting for you: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251

Comment: Is there something like `insert into members.tbl_member default values` in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `default values`

```
INSERT INTO members.tbl_member 
DEFAULT VALUES
RETURNING 
    member_id AS MemberID,
    date_created AS DateCreated, 
    date_modified AS DateModified,
    date_security AS DateSecurity
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DEFAULT for this:

```
INSERT INTO members.tbl_member(date_created) -- you could mention all columns
VALUES (DEFAULT) -- if needed, mention the others as well
RETURNING 
    member_id AS MemberID,
    date_created AS DateCreated, 
    date_modified AS DateModified,
    date_security AS DateSecurity;
```

Comment: You can also use NULL in case table don't have defaults:
INSERT INTO members.tbl_member
       VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
       RETURNING 
            member_id AS MemberID,
            date_created AS DateCreated, 
            date_modified AS DateModified,
            date_security AS DateSecurity

Comment: @SoniaValeja, all columns in a table have a DEFAULT even if not specified in the column definition. That DEFAULT is NULL, the per [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html): *DEFAULT default_expr ... If there is no default for a column, then the default is null.*.